# Erlang translation of Go walk trees

Tags: design-patterns, go, concurrency, erlang

I am trying to implement the `Walk` function from [here](http://golang.org/doc/play/tree.go) which is implemented in Go into erlang.

Here is the result:

```
-module(tree).
-export([walk/1,test/0]).


walk({Left, Value, Right}) ->
    spawn(tree,walk,[Left]),
    io:format(Value),
    spawn(tree,walk,[Right]);
walk({}) -> continue.



test() ->
B = {{}, alina, {}},
D = {{},vlad,{}},
C = {D, tea, {}},
A = {B,maria,C},
walk(A).
```

I'm not sure if this belongs to the code review section as I'm not sure that what I did is what I wanted. The code works as expected (in the sense that it does walk a tree) however I'm not sure if the design of the function is concurrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The function is indeed concurrent, as you are spawning new processes to walk the subtrees.**

You might want to alter `tree:walk/1` so that it returns the atom `ok` in the case of a successful walk (I also switch out `io:format/1` with `erlang:display` so that values are printed on separate lines):

```
walk({Left, Value, Right}) ->
    spawn(tree,walk,[Left]),
    erlang:display(Value),
    spawn(tree,walk,[Right]),
    ok;
walk({}) -> continue.
```

Here is a synchronous version of the same function. Instead of processes, we use recursion:

```
walk_sync({Left, Value, Right}) ->
    walk_sync(Left),
    erlang:display(Value),
    walk_sync(Right);
walk_sync({}) -> continue.
```

Comment: fwiw you can insert newlines using the "tilde escape" [format codes](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-1), which are similar to the classic C printf style, but use "~" rather than "\" as a prefix. So, `io:format("~n")` outputs a newline.